# Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate 'RazorIssue.Pages.UserModel'

Tags: asp.net-identity

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'RazorIssue.Pages.UserModel'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure identity is configured.

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
   //add if needed
   options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And inject `SignInManager<IdentityUser>` to page model.

```
public class UserModel
{
   private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
   public UserModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
   {
      _signInManager = signInManager;
   }
}
```